# Function gets called multiple times when window is resized [JQuery]

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's what I'm trying to do:

-When window's width is less than 700px and user clicks on the gray bar at bottom, a red menu will slide up and stay there.

-When window's width is more than 700px, then nothing will happen when user clicks gray bar.

I've bind a resize() event to the browser window so the changes will be detected if user resizes window after the page loads.

Here's my codepen: **http://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/xwrpWG**
(don't click yet till you read below!)

**Here's how to produce the weird issue:**

1) Before clicking the Codepen link above, resize your window to below 700px, THEN click my codepen above (if unsure how wide is 700px, make it real small)

2) Click the gray bar at the bottom. A red rectangle should slide up and stop. 
Click again. The red rectangle slides back. Click again and again, the red rect slides up and down each time. This is the **CORRECT** behaviour.

3) Now, resize the browser width without re-loading or refreshing the codepen.
You can make it wider or narrower, doesn't matter as long as window is resized.
Click the gray bar again. Bug appears. The red rectangle slides up down **MULTIPLE** times!

Sometimes, the more times you resize, the more times it slides! :-O

How do I fix this?

```js
//bind click event to the gray bar on page's first load
showMenuIfWidthSmallerThanSevenHundred();

//detect window resizes
$(window).resize(function() {
  showMenuIfWidthSmallerThanSevenHundred();
});


function showMenuIfWidthSmallerThanSevenHundred() {
  if ($(window).innerWidth() <= 700) {
    $("div").on("click", function() {
      /* make menu fill the entire screen that is
      not occupied by the gray bar */
      var nMenuHeight = $(window).height() - $(this).height();

      $(".menu").height(nMenuHeight);

      /* position the menu so that the bottom of the menu
      touches the top of the gray bar */
      $(".menu").css("bottom", $(this).height());

      //make menu slide upwards / downwards
      $(".menu").slideToggle();
    });
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 53px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #F08080;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>

<div class="menu"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you bind _event handler_ inside _resize_ event handler. Thus its being called multiple times

Comment: You are binding a click event on each resize (which can be called hundred times) if condition is true...

Comment: That means I should put the click event part outside of the showMenuIfWidthSmallerThanSevenHundred() function? Perhaps put it in the document.ready() function? Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after reading the hints and replies here, I think I nailed this s*** down:

http://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/rOwPEm

If window is less than 700px wide and gray bar is clicked, red rect slides up. When clicked again, red rect slides down.

If window is more than 700px wide, no red rect slides up when gray bar is clicked.
If red rect is visible when user resizes browser width to more than 700px, the red rect will slide back down since width is already more than 700px.

I love Underscore.js! Cheers!

```js
$(window).resize(_.debounce(function() {
  showMenuIfWidthSmallerThan7Hundred();
}, 500));

function showMenuIfWidthSmallerThan7Hundred() {
  if ($(window).innerWidth() <= 700) {
    $("div").off("click.mynamespace").on("click.mynamespace", function() {
      /* make menu fill the entire screen that is
      not occupied by the gray bar */
      var nMenuHeight = $(window).height() - $(this).height();

      $(".menu").height(nMenuHeight);

      /* position the menu so that the bottom of the menu
      touches the top of the gray bar */
      $(".menu").css("bottom", $(this).height());

      //make menu slide upwards / downwards
      $(".menu").slideToggle();
    });
  }
  //if window is wider than 700px, unbind the click event and slide   the menu back down
  else {
    //check if menu is shown. if yes, make it disappear
    if ($(".menu").css("display") != "none") {
      $(".menu").slideToggle();
    }

    $("div").off("click.mynamespace");
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 53px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #F08080;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<div></div>

<div class="menu"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a debounce to fire the event less times. I recommend the Paul Irish's smartresizer, that uses debouces to this purpose.

http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/

AS tutorial said, you can use with this simple listener:

```
 $(window).smartresize(function(){
    // code that takes it easy...
 });
```

You can debounce the tons firing events, like resize, scroll, etc.

Comment: You are missing the nested handler part which is even worst than the debouncing one (which is good point though)

Comment: Tks Marcos! I'm using Underscore.js now.

Comment: So better, because underscore have a `_.debounce()` too. But it's exactly the same that I tell you.